# Pass router paramters to component

Tags: angular, parameters, components, router

In the mainComponent of my angular website I read the url param in this way:

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(){ 
   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
   const id = params['id'];
   console.log(id);
});
}
```

This is how I set the routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'contatti', component: ContattiComponent },
{ path: 'main/:id', component: MainComponent }
];
```

How can I pass the "id" to the contactComponent?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, reading router params from your routing can be done like this:

```
constructor( private router: Router){
}

someId: any;


ngOnInit(){
  this.route.params
        .subscribe( (data: any) => this.someId = data.id //<-- here is your id);

    }
```

**Update**

There is little information about your component structure. So let's assume that your main component contains the template for your other components

Then through your template you can pass the id to the other components:

```
<contatti-component
 [myId]="someId">
</contatti-component>
```

Comment: Nope I want to pass the param read in ManinComponent from ManinComponent to ContactComponent

Comment: @Francesco let my bite the bullet again... I hope this time I guessed correctly what you need

Comment: no, main component does not contain ContactComponent, they are not related

Comment: @dalarzo can't I store the "id" like a global variable and then read it from the contact component?